# Deleting specific object from ArrayList using for-loop

Tags: java

I am trying to delete one object from an ArrayList, but after iterating through the list with the for loop i'm stuck at what to do next. nameInput is a lowercase string from the user.

If i run this it prints the object from arr list equal to the input from nameInput. But I cannot understand how to go from printing that object to deleting it?

I'm sure this is a stupid question but the 50+ answers i have read and tried all seem to fail me (or more likely I fail to understand them). I have tried the list.remove and removeIf.

```
private ArrayList<Arr> arr = new ArrayList<>();

private void removeItem() {
    for (Object arr : arr) {
        if (((Arr) arr).getName().equals(nameInput())) {
            System.out.println(arr);        
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things here...

1. The loop variable receiver type should ideally be `Arr` instead of `Object` as the list contains `Arr` objects. This also means you no longer need the cast you're performing.
2. You could remove the item via `remove(Object o)` but this requires overriding `equals` and `hashcode` based on `name` only. Another option is via an iterator but this would mean changing your code completely. Thus, to keep it as close to your code as possible you can use a `for` loop; get the index which the object is located and then remove.

Thus, you can do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
    if (arr.get(i).getName().equals(nameInput)) {
          Arr obj = arr.remove(i); // remove the item by index     
          System.out.println(obj);  // print the object             
          break;  // terminate the loop iteration
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Using for loop

```
List<Arr> arr = new ArrayList<>();

for (Arr item : arr) {
    if (item.getName().equals(nameInput())) {
        arr.remove(item);
        break;
    }
}
```

If not call `break` after remove element, you get `ConcurrentElementException`

Note from **@Aomine**: you have to implement correct `Arr.equals()` method.

---

#### Using Iterator

```
List<Arr> arr = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<Arr> it = arr.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    Arr items = it.next();

    if (item.getName().equals(nameInput())) {
        it.remove();
        break;  // you can continue iterating and remove another item
    }

}
```

---

#### Using Streams

```
List<Arr> arr = new ArrayList<>();
arr.removeIf(item -> item.getName().equals(nameInput()));
```

Remove all items that match given condition

---

This is not good to remove element from `ArrayList`. In case you know that you have to remove element from the middle of the `List`, do use `LinkedList`.

Comment: I'd also point out that `arr.remove(item);` requires overriding `equals` and `hashcode` in `Arr` based on the `name`.

Comment: @Aomine sure, thank you. But `hasCode()` is not using in this case. It is for `HashMap`.

Comment: You're welcome ;). I always suggest overriding both regardless of whether you only need `equals`. it's good practice.

Comment: If you rely on `equals()` and that only the name field matters for that. `arr.remove(new Arr(name));` is enough. The loop is helpless.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to remove an item while you are traversing/iterating the list in the `for` loop. You cannot remove an item from the list iterating it in a for loop. Use an `Iterator` instead  and invoke `arr.remove()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java 8 you could do

```
private void removeItem() {
    arr.removeIf(t -> t.getName().equals(nameInput));
}
```

Note that this will remove all objects with name equal to `nameInput`

Also you should change your declaration of `arr` to

```
List<Arr> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: this will remove **all** the objects satisfying the provided predicate instead of just the **first**

Comment: @Aomine I don't think that is an issue but it's worth pointing out in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: The "issue" is that it is not what the OP does in its posted code. We exit the loop as soon as the first match and removal.

Comment: @davidxxx no but I get the impression each item (name) is unique. And really it is up to OP to decide if this is acceptable/correct or not